# Is it a kind of Mutant?

Tags: riddle

One mutation helps lunch, while your wounds it is healing.
In the corporate world one helps you to ceiling.

One is part of a thing that is often sequential
Or is sometimes inspired, often thought presidential.

With its friend one can drive you to feelings of shame,
With friend's brother it gives you a feeling of fame.

One mutation is paramount to sweet acts of couplings,
Then, afterward, It will again hide your dumplings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the answer is:

> **Dress**

One mutation helps lunch, while your wounds it is healing.

> This mutation is:  **...ing**
>  giving **dressing**, a sauce or similar for your lunch, or a bandage for a wound.

In the corporate world one helps you to ceiling.

> This mutation is, perhaps, **...for success** or **...coat**, or **power...**
>  giving **dress for success** or **dress coat** or **power dress**, all the same idea of (wearing) attire intended to show that one holds an important position in business.

One is part of a thing that is often sequential
Or is sometimes inspired, often thought presidential.

> This mutation is: **ad...**
>  giving **address**; street addresses may be sequential, and speaking addresses, including presidential addresses, are often inspired.

With its friend one can drive you to feelings of shame,

> Its friend is, perhaps, **...down** -
>  To **[dress down](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dress%20down)** someone could well evoke shame.

With friend's brother it gives you a feeling of fame.

> Friend's brother is then **...up** -
>  To **dress up** can make you feel more glamorous or more like someone famous.

One mutation is paramount to sweet acts of couplings,

> This mutation is likely: **un...**
>  giving **undress**, an paramount step in paramours' couplings

Then, afterward, It will again hide your dumplings.

> The original word, without any mutations, brings us back to **dress** -
>  letting you hide whatever sort of *dumplings* you've got on ya.

Comment: I got the "dressing" part right, then, that's something.

Answer (score 10):

My understanding of the riddle is that

> the answer is some specific word, and each of the "mutations" gives a definition/explanation of a word that is the same as the answer but with one letter changed.

Is this correct at least? If so, I have a partial solution, which is extremely unlikely to be right but please hear me out. I believe the answer is

> the word **rang**. Each "mutated" clue that I've figured out is one letter away from **rang**.

"In the corporate world, one helps you to ceiling" could refer to a

> **rung**, as in a rung on the corporate ladder.

"One is part of a thing that is often sequential" could refer to a

> **rank** in an organizational chart/hierarchy.

"Sometimes inspired, often thought presidential" could refer to a

> **rant**. Rants can be very passionate, and are frequently on the subject of politics, including (especially this year) presidents.

"One mutation is paramount to sweet acts of couplings" could refer to a

> **ring**, which is always used to symbolize an act of coupling at a wedding.

Again, one in a million shot but I figured I'd throw it out there.

Comment: Thank you for restoring my faith in the ranks of the riddle-solvers. I high-plus-one-your assertion. I'll readdress my question. Your think that this a specific word is thoughtful and thunk. I've rethunk it through and had its thouthfulness thinked through.

Answer (score 2):

I may not be able to explain everything, but to me it is the word

> digits

One is part of a thing that is often sequential

> A digit is a part of a number series

In the corporate world one helps you to ceiling

> In corporate world digits can take one high

With its friend one can drive you to feelings of shame

> with (-)negative sign its bad i.e., you are in debt

With friend's brother it gives you a feeling of fame

> With +(positive) you are rich

Answer (score 1):

I have a partial answer.

One mutation helps lunch, while your wounds it is healing.
In the corporate world one helps you to ceiling.

> Dressing (salad dressing, 'dressings' for wounds, and 'dressing for success')

One mutation is paramount to sweet acts of couplings,

> Could be "blessing" (in order to get married, you traditionally need to get the blessing of the father of the bride-to-be).

I don't know whether I'm going down the right path here...

Answer (score 0):

Is it

> A suit?

Because

> You're more probable to rise up (figuratively towards the ceiling) in a corporate world with a proper suit.

And

> Suits seem presidential and give a feeling of fame.

And

> A man usually gets married (acts of couplings) in a suit.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Puzzling! Could you add some spoilertags (use `>!` at the start of a paragraph) so that people don't see the answer accidentally without meaning to?